# sorting of strings in the order short long short

Tags: python-3.x, string

```
  if a > b:
    return b + a + b
  else:
    return a + b + a
```

This for some reason doesn't consistently return the strings in the order short long short

Comment: You need to compare the *lengths* of the strings. That is, `if len(a) > len(b): ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the "len" method to adjudicate between two strings.